# How to make sure a .tar.gz file is valid and will uncompress correctly?

Tags: linux, tar, gzip

I have a few BIG .tar.gz files, and I want to make sure they will uncompress, but without actually doing it.

If the file opens on "Archive Manager" on Ubuntu, and I can view it contents there, does that mean the .tar.gz will successfully uncompress when I try to?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it, but it could be ... Hurans, are you trying to check the file using a PHP script? (assuming this is the case from other recently posted question)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a Unix .tar.gz file is a valid file without uncompressing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001709/how-to-check-if-a-unix-tar-gz-file-is-a-valid-file-without-uncompressing)

Answer (score 1):

Good lads provide cryptographic checksums like MD5, SHA1 or SHA256 together with big .tar.gz files. Match the computed checksum against the original one. This is a good bet that your file is healthy (assuming the original checksum wasn't computed against a broken tarball).

Answer (score 0):

No easy way - as `.tar.gz` are compressed, in order for `tar` to check anything, it needs to uncompress it through `gzip`. The closest you can get is list the file:

```
tar -tzf file.tar.gz
```

but that will trigger uncompressing (the `.gz` part), so if your file is big, you will have to wait, especially if you are doing it over network. Locally, I think you should be rather OK - you are going to wait, but it's going to finish in a few hours or a day unless we are talking TBs.